# Bad request while trying to get authToken using docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docuSign API and I followed the code sample for C# in DocuSign guide site. I failed at the step while I was trying to get AuthToken. Part of my code as below, basically the same as the DocuSign sample,

```
public void OAuthAuthorizationCodeFlowTest()
{
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // Make an API call with the token
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(RestApiUrl);
        DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

        // Initiate the browser session to the Authentication server
        // so the user can login.
        string accountServerAuthUrl = 
        apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(client_id, redirect_uri, true, 
        stateOptional);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(accountServerAuthUrl);

        string accessToken = apiClient.GetOAuthToken(client_id, 
        client_secret, true, AccessCode);
        // login call is available in the authentication api 
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

       // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to 
       multiple accounts)
        AccountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
        BaseUri = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
        Console.WriteLine("accountId: " + AccountId);
        Console.WriteLine("base_uri: " + BaseUri);
```

The client_id is my integrator key, the client_secret is the secret key related to that integrator key, right? I checked them many times, no problem. I am confused now why am I still getting 400 error. Please shed me some light here, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(accountServerAuthUrl);` will open it on a browser, and once you have done successful authentication then browser will be redirected with the query parameter `code=....` in the callback url (`redirect_uri`)

The code in browser needs to be read by your WEBApp, and then you need to call below code to generate the AccessToken:

```
string accessToken = apiClient.GetOAuthToken(client_id, 
        client_secret, true, AccessCode);
```

Below code is one part, to open the browser, ideally it is for testing purpose on a Standalone system, on a WEBApp you will redirect the browser to `accountServerAuthUrl`

```
public void OAuthAuthorizationCodeFlowTest()
        {

            // Make an API call with the token
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(RestApiUrl);
            DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            // Initiate the browser session to the Authentication server
            // so the user can login.
            string accountServerAuthUrl = apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(client_id, redirect_uri, true, stateOptional);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(accountServerAuthUrl);
        }
```

Below code is run when user is authenticated by the DocuSign on the browser and browser is redirected to the `redirect_uri` with `code=...`, your Webapp will read this code and send it as `AccessCode` and will call below code from your controller,

```
string accessToken = apiClient.GetOAuthToken(client_id, client_secret, true, AccessCode);
```